# Artifacts randomly appearing around transparent PNGs

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I'm using a few Spark BitmapImage components to display transparent PNGs in my GUI. Sometimes when I display said interface, I get weird artifacts around borders of these components or their parent containers. These artifacts only appear sometimes when I display the GUI, and disappear if I do anything on the interface, such as a click or a drag action.

Here is an example of what I'm calling artifacts:

[image: Example of artifacts around a PNG with transparent background]

Some of these image components have a DropShadowFilter set on them, if that might help.
For now I couldn't identify specific workflows or behaviours to trigger this bug, so any clues will be appreciated.

Comment: A workaround would be to trace the PNG-images in Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape and export them as [FXG-files](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSda78ed3a750d6b8f26c150d412357de3591-8000.html).

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Thanks for your comment, but unfortunately I don't have the possibility to do this. I've been given the assets as PNGs and can't redo them myself (the one from the screenshot is one of the simplest cases)